# C99 The reason float value 1.000000 turns into 3.000000?

Tags: c, c99

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float x = 1.0;
    int *p=(int *)&x;
    *p=1077936128;
    printf("x=%f, *p=%d\n",x,*p);
}
```

The result is x=3.000000, *p=1077936128 .

I can't understand the number '3.000000' is why in there. 
May I ask this?

Comment: It's quite possible that the compiler deduces that "x" is constant because there's no writes via a legal pointer (the `*p = 1077936128` statement is a write via the wrong type -- which is undefined in standard C via the "strict aliasing" rule), and the output is `x=1.000000, *p=1077936128`. Maybe tomorrow if not today. Undefined behavior is to be avoided...

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing basically is you are changing a float(32 bit floating point number) with a integer pointer.This causes a confusion in the compiler.

The structure for 1.0 float in binary is:

**0   01111111 00000000000000000000000**

And the structure for 3.0 as well as 1077936128 is:

**01000000010000000000000000000000**

Read more about [float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Good answer, but also this is undefined behaviour; you can't count on this to always happen. Nasal demons. To get it to be defined, use a `union`.

Comment: @Neil You're right. The undefined behaviour is compiler dependent.

Comment: @Neil The question was not, "How can I set a `float` variable to 3.0?"  If that were the question, then this would be a bad answer, unacceptably relying on undefined behavior.  But no, the question was "Why did this (strange) program behave this way?", and Programmerabc has adequately explained it.  Saying "It's undefined and not guaranteed to work that way" would not have helped the OP understand why that *particular* strange result was achieved.

Comment: @SteveSummit I think so, too; that's why I upvoted it. However, as a side note, you should never do this intentionally.